# Can I install Kubuntu on my laptop?

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

I want to ask if I can run Kubuntu properly on my laptop. I have a Toshiba Satellite A200-1MD from 2007 with 4GB RAM, Intel core i5 running at 2 GHz processor speed and 128 storage.

Comment: Download a "Live CD" or "Live USB" and try to boot it.

Comment: Why don't you tell us if you can? :-) kUbuntu is free. So all it will take is a bit of your time to make a live dvd and boot from it. By the way: "Can I install" is a question that we can not answer as we do not know your level of expertise. Plus installing it and being able to use it are also 2 different issues. It will be slow on a 2007 machine but if it is workable for you or me might have a different answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems to fullfill the [requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

If you want to be sure, you can first **Try Ubuntu**.

There is an instruction for Ubuntu. It seems a bit different on Kunbutu, but there are the same texts.
You can follow [this insctruction](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).